# SQL Update and CASE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I want to update `new_BantuanKewangan` from `STU_TYPC` table with `CASE`:

```
UPDATE DMSTAG.dbo.TEMP_AKAUN_MARA
SET [new_BantuanKewangan] = [STU_TYPC] 
FROM [SMBM_DBPELJ].[DBPELJ].[MSTUMASTER]
  (CASE
  when [new_BantuanKewangan] = '00' then 'Yes'
  when [new_BantuanKewangan] = '01' then 'No')
  where DMSTAG.dbo.TEMP_AKAUN_MARA.STUDENTN = [SMBM_DBPELJ].[DBPELJ].[MSTUMASTER].STUDENT
```

Error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: you are missing END in your case statement. Besides that, why you putting case statement after from?

Comment: Are you trying to update [new_BantuanKewangan] field based on '00' and '01'? If so, then your statement might be something like


UPDATE DMSTAG.dbo.TEMP_AKAUN_MARA
  set [new_BantuanKewangan] = (CASE
 when [new_BantuanKewangan] = '00' then 'Yes'
 when [new_BantuanKewangan] = '01' then 'No'
 end)
  from [SMBM_DBPELJ].[DBPELJ].[MSTUMASTER]
  where DMSTAG.dbo.TEMP_AKAUN_MARA.STUDENTN = [SMBM_DBPELJ].[DBPELJ].[MSTUMASTER].STUDENT

Comment: @bsting: You code is correct. But, my situation is I want to transfer data from SMBM_DBPELJ (tbl) STU_TYPC (field) to TEMP_AKAUN_MARA (tbl) new_BantuanKewangan (field) how to combine all the code with CASE above?

Comment: the source table is SMBM_DBPELJ  or [SMBM_DBPELJ].[DBPELJ].[MSTUMASTER]? Also, in your case statement, which field actually you are refer to "when [new_BantuanKewangan]" or "when [STU_TYPC]"?

Comment: @bsting: If original data from STU_TYPC.

Comment: Not sure what u mean of original data from STU_TYPC, is this what you try to achieve?



UPDATE DMSTAG.dbo.TEMP_AKAUN_MARA
  set DMSTAG.dbo.TEMP_AKAUN_MARA.[new_BantuanKewangan] = (CASE
  when [SMBM_DBPELJ].[DBPELJ].[MSTUMASTER].[STU_TYPC]  = '00' then 'Yes'
  when [SMBM_DBPELJ].[DBPELJ].[MSTUMASTER].[STU_TYPC] = '01' then 'No')
  from [SMBM_DBPELJ].[DBPELJ].[MSTUMASTER]
  where DMSTAG.dbo.TEMP_AKAUN_MARA.STUDENTN = [SMBM_DBPELJ].[DBPELJ].[MSTUMASTER].STUDENT

Comment: Please ***do not put code*** samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: @bsting: Thank you very much. Hope you can post your answer, so I can tick resolve.

Comment: @MUHDMAN I have posted it to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE DMSTAG.dbo.TEMP_AKAUN_MARA 
SET DMSTAG.dbo.TEMP_AKAUN_MARA.[new_BantuanKewangan] = 
                       (CASE 
                         WHEN [SMBM_DBPELJ].[DBPELJ].[MSTUMASTER].[STU_TYPC] = '00' THEN 'Yes' 
                         WHEN [SMBM_DBPELJ].[DBPELJ].[MSTUMASTER].[STU_TYPC] = '01' then 'No') 
FROM [SMBM_DBPELJ].[DBPELJ].[MSTUMASTER] 
WHERE DMSTAG.dbo.TEMP_AKAUN_MARA.STUDENTN = [SMBM_DBPELJ].[DBPELJ].[MSTUMASTER].STUDENT
```